# MySQL: Get top 1 IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to select the 1st property ID per client ID that gets associated to the Customer ID. Please help. How would I query this?

```
PropertyID  ClientID    CustomerID  Date
       10    1                 35    2004
       20    1                 35    2004
       30    2                 35    2004
       40    2                 35    2004
       50    3                 35    2004
       60    3                 35    2004
       70    4                 35    2004
       80    4                 35    2004
       90    5                 35    2004
      100    5                 35    2004
      110    6                 35    2005
      120    6                 35    2005
      130    7                 35    2005
      140    7                 35    2005
      150    8                 35    2005
      160    8                 35    2005
      170    9                 35    2005
      180    9                 35    2005
      220    15                37    2007
      240    15                37    2007
      260    16                37    2007
      270    16                37    2007
```

Expected Result:

```
PropertyID   ClientID   CustomerID
   10            1           35
   30            2           35
   50            3           35
   70            4           35
   90            5           35
   110           6           35
   130           7           35
   150           8           35 
   170           9           35
   220           15          37
   260           16          37
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MIN(PropertyID) AS PropertyID, ClientID, CustomerID
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ClientID,CustomerID;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3dce/1

for example

Comment: @Strawberry before claiming anyone please check at least once, for more detail please visit http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3dce/1

Comment: Ok, but before I do, does your result match the OP's?

Comment: @Strawberry YES!! you can check on mention sqlfiddle link Expected Result in question and my answer is same.

Comment: Now add date to the result

Comment: @Strawberry why add date in result, have any date column is mention in Expected Result??

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by 1st you mean with lowest propertyId, you can use aggregation in subquery to find the lowest propertyId per clientId and then join the results with the original table to get the other corresponding columns.

```
select propertyId, clientId, customerId
from your_table t
join (
    select clientId,
        min(propertyId) as propertyId
    from your_table
    group by clientId
    ) t2 using (clientId, propertyId);
```

This assumes the propertyId is unique (per client at least).

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/WKW86633)

Comment: Using this, I get unknown column ' propertyID' in from clause.

Comment: @DariusCastillo - Well you have given it in the sample data in your question. Just change it to whatever column you have in your actual table. See this demo - http://rextester.com/WKW86633